# Windbus sample application does not start (Could not parse server address error)

Tags: c++, windows, dbus

I am trying to start some sample application which uses dbus on windows.
I have started dbus-daemon.exe --session and then started sample application, which calls this:

```
// connect to the bus and check for errors
conn = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &err);
if (dbus_error_is_set(&err)) { 
   fprintf(stderr, "Connection Error (%s)\n", err.message);
   dbus_error_free(&err); 
}
if (NULL == conn) { 
   exit(1);
}
```

but it always exits and error message is following: "Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")

What can be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. Changing DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM  to DBUS_BUS_SESSION solved my problem.